Problem building query sequelize-typescript
I am currently facing an issue when creating a query with sequelize-typescript. The problem arises when trying to fetch records from a many-to-many relationship. Here is the SQL query I am trying to replicate using sequelize-typescript:
SELECT 
    T0.id, T0.name, T0.image, T0.age, T0.history, T0.created_by, T0.updated_by
FROM public.characters T0
    LEFT JOIN public.products_characters T1 ON T0.id = T1.character_id
    LEFT JOIN public.products T2 ON T1.product_id = T2.id
WHERE T0.deleted_at IS NULL AND T1.product_id != 'c011972c-ebff-4d88-840b-c62be6d91bd5'
    OR T0.deleted_at IS NULL AND T1.character_id IS NULL;

With this query, I get all characters that are NOT related to a product, as well as those that have no relationship with any product.
I’ve tried several approaches without success. Here is the sequelize query I have worked on so far:
return await CharacterModel.findAndCountAll({
    where: queryParams.filters,
    order: [["createdAt", "desc"]],
    limit: queryParams.limit,
    offset: queryParams.offset,
    attributes: {
        exclude: ['updatedAt', 'deletedAt', 'products']
    },
    include: {
        model: ProductModel,
        required: false,
        through: {
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { productId: { [Op.ne]: productId } },
                    { characterId: null }
                ]
            },
            attributes: []
        },
        attributes: []
    }
});

With the above sequelize query, I am getting all characters, as if the filter parameters are not being applied.
This is the query that is generated in the log from the sequelize query:
Executing (default): SELECT 
    "CharacterModel"."id", 
    "CharacterModel"."name", 
    "CharacterModel"."image", 
    "CharacterModel"."age", 
    "CharacterModel"."history", 
    "CharacterModel"."created_by" AS "createdBy", 
    "CharacterModel"."updated_by" AS "updatedBy", 
    "CharacterModel"."created_at" AS "createdAt", 
    "CharacterModel"."updated_at" AS "updatedAt", 
    "CharacterModel"."deleted_at" AS "deletedAt", 
    "products"."id" AS "products.id", 
    "products"."title" AS "products.title" 
FROM "characters" AS "CharacterModel" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    "products_characters" AS "products->ProductCharacterModel" 
    INNER JOIN "products" AS "products" ON "products"."id" = "products->ProductCharacterModel"."product_id"
    ) ON "CharacterModel"."id" = "products->ProductCharacterModel"."character_id" 
    AND ("products"."deleted_at" IS NULL) 
    WHERE (
        "CharacterModel"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
        AND "CharacterModel"."id" = '0b473d73-d4da-4adc-ad4e-5e976fa964a5'
    );

These are my sequelize-typescript models:
Character Model
import { BelongsToMany, Column, CreatedAt, DataType, DeletedAt, Model, Table, UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { ProductCharacterModel } from "../product/product-character.model";
import { ProductModel } from "../product/product.model";

@Table({
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'characters',
    paranoid: true,
    modelName: 'CharacterModel',
})
export class CharacterModel extends Model {

    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'id',
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
    })
    declare id: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(100),
        field: 'name',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    })
    declare name: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(255),
        field: 'image',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
    })
    declare image: string | null | undefined;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(3),
        field: 'age',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare age: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.TEXT,
        field: 'history',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare history: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'created_by',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare createdBy: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'updated_by',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare updatedBy: string;

    @CreatedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'created_at',
    })
    declare createdAt: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'updated_at',
    })
    declare updatedAt: Date;

    @DeletedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'deleted_at',
    })
    declare deletedAt: Date;

    @BelongsToMany(() => ProductModel, () => ProductCharacterModel)
    products!: ProductModel[];

}

Product Character Model N:M
import { CharacterModel } from "../character/character.model";
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table, ForeignKey } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { ProductModel } from "./product.model";

@Table({
    tableName: 'products_characters',
    timestamps: false,
})
export class ProductCharacterModel extends Model {
    @ForeignKey(() => ProductModel)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'product_id',
    })
    declare productId: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => CharacterModel)
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'character_id',
    })
    declare characterId: string;
}

Product Model
import { BelongsTo, BelongsToMany, Column, CreatedAt, DataType, DeletedAt, Model, Table, UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { CharacterModel } from "../character/character.model";
import { GenderModel } from "./gender.model";
import { KindModel } from "./kind.model";
import { ProductCharacterModel } from "./product-character.model";
import { Qualification } from "../../lib-entities/products/product/product.entity";

@Table({
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'products',
    paranoid: true,
    modelName: 'ProductModel',
})
export class ProductModel extends Model {
    @Column({
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'id',
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
    })
    declare id: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(100),
        field: 'title',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    })
    declare title: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING(255),
        field: 'image',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare image: string | null | undefined;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'created_date',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare createdDate: Date;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),
        field: 'qualification',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare qualification: Qualification;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'gender_id',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare genderId: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'kind_id',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: false,
    })
    declare kindId: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'created_by',
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    })
    declare createdBy: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        field: 'updated_by',
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
    })
    declare updatedBy: string;

    @CreatedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'created_at',
    })
    declare createdAt: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'updated_at',
    })
    declare updatedAt: Date;

    @DeletedAt
    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        field: 'deleted_at',
    })
    declare deletedAt: Date;

    @BelongsTo(() => GenderModel, {
        foreignKey: 'genderId',
        targetKey: 'id',
    })
    declare gender: GenderModel;

    @BelongsTo(() => KindModel, {
        foreignKey: 'kindId',
        targetKey: 'id',
    })
    declare kind: KindModel;

    @BelongsToMany(() => CharacterModel, () => ProductCharacterModel)
    characters!: CharacterModel[];
}

I hope you can help me realize what I'm doing wrong, thanks for your help!

If you add a condition on included model and expect that the main model records will be filtered by that condition you shouldn't indicate required: false which leads to LEFT OUTER JOIN that in its turn ignores all conditions for the table indicated after it.

Please validate the query again, there was a slight error in a join.

Try to indicate required: true and compare the queires

Yes, I already tried it that way, but it only shows me the records that exist in the Characters table and are related to the ProductsCharacters table. But the new Characters that are not related to a product do not appear.

Can you add the generated SQL to the post for required: false?

I added the query that generates sequelize in the question information.

It seems the generated SQL and the Sequelize query above do not match (judging by conditions)
